# Laravel multiple function in a view

Tags: laravel

i need help, i'm new in laravel, i want to make query to get year only from table like this

```
public function index() {
    $items = Items::distinct()->orderBy('date','desc')->select(DB::raw('YEAR(`date`) as date'))->get();
    $itemDet = Items::where('date', $items->date);
}
```

then i want to show other value from table based on year above with this function

```
public function itemDetail($year) {
    $itemDet = Items::where('YEAR(`date`)', $year);

    return $itemDet;
}
```

But i don't know how to call it in view, i only know how to call the first function in a view, and I don't know how to pass value year from first function as parameters to second function.

```
2018
- item2018
- item2018
- item2018
2017
- item2017
2016
-item2016
-item2016
```

sorry for my bad grammar, thank you!

Comment: Read [Laravel View Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views). And remember StackOverflow is not a tutorial website. You must learn things from official documentation. And discuss here if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function itemDetail($year) {
    $itemDet = Items::where('YEAR(`date`)', $year);

    //return $itemDet; change it to 
    return view('yourViewPath',compact('itemDet'));
}
```

in view you can access like this way

```
{{ $itemDet }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that output right away in your index function without passing it to second function, one way to do it.

```
public function index() {

    $arr_container = []; //create array container

    $items = Items::distinct()->orderBy('date','desc')->select(DB::raw('YEAR(`date`) as date'))->get();
    foreach($items as $val){
       $itemDet = Items::select(DB::raw('item'))->where('YEAR(`date`)', $val->year)->get();
       if($itemDet->count()>0){
        $arr_container[$val->year][] = $itemDet[0]->item;
       }
    }

    return view('view')->with('years',$arr_container);
}
```

You should get this output when you call {{$years}}.

```
2018
- item2018
- item2018
- item2018
2017
- item2017
2016
-item2016
-item2016
```